# Построить запрос к БД Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть несколько таблиц:

```
Таблица items - товары
Таблица items_catalogs - Каталоги для товаров
Таблица catalogs - Список каталогов
Таблица handbooks_names - Наименования характеристик для товаров
Таблица handbooks_names_values - Значения характеристик
Таблица item_handbook_values - Связь товара и значения характеристики
```

Задача вывести список значений определённой характеристики для категории товаров, причём только те значения которые есть у товаров текущей категории.

Сейчас запрос к базе выводит просто список значений характеристик без привязки к категории, а нужно что бы выводились только те значения которые есть в товарах для текущей категории.

[image: Таблица items]

[image: Таблица items_catalogs]

[image: Таблица handbooks_names]

[image: Таблица handbooks_names_values]

[image: Таблица item_handbook_values]

[image: Таблица catalogs]

Comment: И в чём у вас проблема?

Comment: В том что у меня в таблице handbooks_names_values нет поля по которому можно было бы вывести только те значения которые относятся к определённой категории.

Comment: То есть не могу понять как построить такой запрос что бы вывести например все значения характеристик вместе с товарами.

Comment: Стройте несколько запросов. Одним можете и не вытянуть. У вас же почти классический EAV

Comment: ArchDemon так это понятно, мне сам запрос не получается построить, пока костыльно сделал, но хочеться понять мне как лучше выбирать все id товаров текущий категории и передовать их потом в запрос к таблице item_handbook_values?

Comment: ну так приведите пример вашего кода в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Миграция каталогов.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCatalogsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('catalogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('catalogs');
    }
}
```

Миграция продуктов.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Миграция связки каталога с продуктом
catalog -> product.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCatalogProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('catalog_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('catalog_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->unique(['catalog_id', 'product_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('catalog_product');
    }
}
```

Миграция foreign key для каталога и продукта catalog_product.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ForeignToCatalogProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('catalog_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('catalog_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('catalogs')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('catalog_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('catalog_product_catalog_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('catalog_product_product_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

Миграция руководств

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateHandbooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('handbooks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('handbooks');
    }
}
```

Миграция связки продукта с руководством, с дополнительным параметром value, который будет передаваться через pivot.
product -> handbook.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductHandbookTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_handbook', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('product_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->integer('handbook_id')
                ->unsigned();
            $table->string('value')
                ->nullable();
            $table->unique(['product_id', 'handbook_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_handbook');
    }
}
```

Миграция foreign key для продукта и руководства product_handbook.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ForeignToProductHandbookTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('product_handbook', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('handbook_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('handbooks')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('product_handbook', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('product_handbook_product_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('product_handbook_handbook_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

Модель продукта со связками

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function catalogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Catalog::class,
            'catalog_product'
        );
    }

    public function handbooks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Handbook::class,
            'product_handbook'
        )->withPivot('value')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Запись :

```
$product = Product::create($data);

$product->catalogs()
    ->attach($request->catalogs);

$product->handbooks()
    ->attach($request->handbooks);
```

Редактирование :

```
$product = Product::where(['id' => $id])
    ->first();

$product->catalogs()
    ->sync($request->catalogs);

$product->handbooks()
    ->sync($request->handbooks);
```

Например pivot - value передать можно так :

```
<input type="hidden" name="handbooks[{{ $handbook->id }}][id]" value="{{ $handbook->id }}">
<input type="text" name="handbooks[{{ $handbook->id }}][value]">
```